# What can justify the big price gap between a Leica M6 and M7?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, leica

Is it only about semi and fully automatic mecanism ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The M6 isn't manufactured anymore, so any M6 you would be buying will be used. That might be a large part of the price difference. The M6 successor, the MP, costs exactly as much ($4995) at B&H as the M7.

There's a [decent article of the M7](http://www.luminous-landscape.com/reviews/cameras/Leica_M7.shtml) (with comparisons to the M6) over at Luminous Landscape.

Please do remember that with Leicas, just like all other cameras, the camera is 20% of the tool, the lens in the other 80%.